# Using Pre Built Toolchain in Yocto Tree

Tags: linux, toolchain, yocto

Is there a way to configure Yocto to use Pre Built toolchain (like downloaded from CodeSourcery, etc.). I want to avoid building toolchain because it takes too much time and using new toolchain is not of my concern.

I was using this feature in buildroot.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, though I'm not using it that often.

For the CodeSourcery-toolchains, have a look at [meta-sourcery](https://github.com/MentorEmbedded/meta-sourcery), which is a layer adding support for the CodeSourcery toolchain.

Basically, you just need to add this layer to `BBLAYERS` in your `conf/bblayers.conf`. Though, make sure that you add it before the meta layer.

Then you should just need to add `s listed before the meta layer, as this ensures meta-sourcery gets priority over meta. Set EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN = "/path/to/your/sourcery-g++-install"` to your `conf/local.conf`.

Be sure to checkout the README.md in meta-sourcery, as there are some extra stuff you might need to be aware of. (Depending on your build machine configuration etc).

Comment: This is for Codesourcery. Is there a way to do this in freescale or generic way ? like I built yocto for IMX6, and I have toolchain tar ball as output. I want use the same toolchain while building it freshly on other PC.

Comment: Well, you mentioned CodeSourcery... If it's for building using bitbake etc on the 2nd computer, I'd recommend to share the sstate-cache between the two computers.

Comment: Hello @Anders, I am trying to enable the external pre-built Sourcery toolchain in yocto as described above, but I'm running into errors and hoped you can help.   Poky-fido-13.0.0 is my distro.  I have cloned the meta-sourcery layer as linked above, and followed directions in the Readme.md to specify it as first layer in bblayers.conf.  Also set EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN in my local.conf.

Comment: (cont'd) But I get this error `But I get this error 
{{{
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home/exacqu/meta-sourcery/recipes-external/glibc/glibc-external.bb: Failure expanding variable PV[:=], expression was ${@get_external_libc_version(d)} which triggered exception TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
}}}
Any ideas to guide direction are appreciated

Comment: Nothing immediately. What src-revs are you using (both poky and meta-sourcery?) Which version of the toolchain? At the moment, I don't have a system setup for this, so it might be a while before I could check anything myself.

Comment: Apologies @Anders I solved the first error I mentioned above as (embarrassing) mistyped toolchain path. Thanks for the help offer!  Now I have to figure out why the do_package step is failing to locate my arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objcopy (this is code sourcery arm2009q1 tool chain).